# Question left abandoned

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I posted [How can I get the image of a diagram by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698100/how-can-i-get-the-image-of-a-diagram-by-code). Someone closed the post because it was not correctly focused. Since a possible action was re-editing the post, I did that.

Two days have elapsed and nothing has happened.
The post is still closed and nobody has sent any kind of feedback.

Is that normal for Stack Overflow?

Comment: What makes you think you are entitled to get the post reopened (which is debatable in itself) before the 2.3 thousand questions currently in the review queue processed entirely by volunteers?

Comment: You seem to be asking "What is the API to accomplish this task"? That doesn't seem like a question that should be reopened. You'd need to change your question substantially for anyone to even consider getting it reopened.

Comment: @10Rep  to be fair that is my edit, to make it a bit less of a "find me an api" and more of  a 'how do I do that' I made another edit to salvage that a bit

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is quite normal that we take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) before anything happens. Moderation is still underpaid here. Most of us would rather be lazy than to put in any work.

I've made another edit to your question, but it is still a bit broad.

Do you want to use [EnvDTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)?

Or make it an extension: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/?view=vs-2019

Or automate Visual Studio from another process?

Not all Visual Studio version are equal. Which version are you using?

It might help if you can add the bits and pieces you already have in place. For example, if you already have the code that gives you the window / document / project item you're interested in and what type it is. From there users can provide missing bits or reveal there is no public method to reach into that one function with automation.

I warn you that not all Views in Visual Studio allow easy automation or automation at all. At least that had been the case for a long time. Accept the answer to your actual question might be "No, that isn't possible".

Once you added this context you have a bit more chance to get it reopened.

Comment: Hi Peter 
Thanks for your message. 
Sorry Peter, I'm not against you. You're the only one who gave a sensible answer. Let me tell you Peter, I feel like an alien! it seems so easy to me: I need a function that can list all diagrams (files with extension * .cd) in a generic visual studio project (any version) and for each of them, saves the diagram as an image file. 
STOP: nothing more, nothing less. I don't think it's possible to be more focused than that !!!! 
Why should I add noise to the message?

Thanks again for your time Peter
Cheers

Vincenzo

Comment: @AlterEgo uh, Peter is an editor of this post, it was made by rene...

Comment: @AlterEgo SO is not a free coding service. That's all. *I need a function that does this and that* is not the way to ask. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).